# How to add together elements in a tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I was wondering how I could add together the elements in each tuple inside a list. Here is my code:

```
def add_together():

    list = [(2,3), (4,5), (9,10)]
    for tuple in list:
        #missing code goes here I think.
            print('{} + {} = {}'.format(x,y,a))
add_together()
```

The output I want would start with

```
2 + 3 = 5
```

How do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuple-unpacking syntax to get each item in the tuple:

```
def add_together(lst):
    for (x, y) in lst:
        print('{} + {} = {}'.format(x,y,x+y))

lst = [(2,3), (4,5), (9,10)]
add_together(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
def add_together():
    input_list = [(2,3), (4,5), (9,10)]
    for tup in input_list:
        #missing code goes here I think.
            print('{} + {} = {}'.format(tup[0],tup[1],tup[0]+tup[1]))
add_together()
```

Output :

```
2 + 3 = 5
4 + 5 = 9
9 + 10 = 19
```

Comment: Oh, ok. So to specify a specific unit inside a tuple I can use name_of_tuple[location_of_unit]?

Comment: Yes correct. you can access the elements of tuple by providing index number. Same goes for list, strings etc.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use * to unpacking the tuples

```
def add_together():
    list = [(2, 3), (4, 5), (9, 10)]
    for tupl in list:
        print('{} + {} = {}'.format(*tupl, sum(tupl)))

add_together()
```

Prints:

```
2 + 3 = 5
4 + 5 = 9
9 + 10 = 19
```